PEP 668 Error (Externally managed environment) within Conda
While trying to pip install packages, even though I am inside a Conda environment, I'm getting the familiar error:
error: externally-managed-environment

I would expect this if I'm using Python directly from the system prompt. But why do I get this even inside the Conda environment?

Ok, after some effort I figured it out.
It gives that error because the Conda environment is somehow using the system Python, from /usr/bin/python3 and /usr/bin/pip3. Check using commands like
$ which python
$ which python3
$ which pip3

You need it to use the instance of Python installed within the active Conda environment. One way to ensure this is to specify a version of Python while creating the Conda environment - this is what I did and it worked. Do something like -
$ conda create -n env1 python=3.10 

If you already explicitly added Python while creating the Conda environment and you still get the same error, you probably have a different problem, google for - Conda using system python.

I can't understand why you expected the Conda environment to have its own Python if you didn't tell it to. It's also common knowledge that Pip isn't expected to work reliably within a Conda environment - because it doesn't understand anything about what Conda is doing to define the environment.
